# Как собрать Maybe<List<User>> из Maybe<User>?

Tags: java, android, rxjava, rxandroid, rxjava2

Есть у меня метод

```
Maybe<User> getUser(int iId){}
```

и есть метод

```
Maybe<List<User>> getUsers(List<Integer> iIds){}
```

Вопрос: как реализовать этот метод?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю лучше возвращать Single вместо Maybe, тогда реализовать можно, например, так:

```
Single<List<User>> getUsers(List<Integer> ids) {
    return Observable.fromIterable(ids)
            .flatMapMaybe((id) -> getUser(id))
            .toList();
}
```

Если все же нужно возвращать Maybe, то можно сделать так:

```
Maybe<List<User>> getUsers(List<Integer> ids) {
    return Observable.fromIterable(ids)
            .flatMapMaybe((id) -> getUser(id))
            .toList()
            .flatMapMaybe((list) -> {
                if (list.isEmpty()) {
                    return Maybe.empty();
                } else {
                    return Maybe.just(list);
                }
            });
}
```